# How to get the default user data to a bitrix form

Tags: forms-authentication, bitrix

I am working on a bitrix site. A form was created linking into an information block that has a sorting of 100.

```
<? echo print_input($arParams, $arResult, 100) ;?>
```

I wanted to use the default user data like name, last name, email etc. of the current log user. How do I approach that?

Any help would much be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

On every page - $USER object is available - it contains information about current logged in user.
Contains this methods to retrieve info about current user:

- GetID
- GetLogin
- GetEmail
- GetFullName
- GetFirstName
- GetLastName
- GetParam
- GetUserGroupArray
- GetUserGroupList
- GetUserGroupString

Or you can use it like this

```
<?php
    global $USER;
    $rsUser = CUser::GetByID($USER->GetID());
    $arUser = $rsUser->Fetch();

    // print current user info
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arUser); echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

[here is more info about CUser class in official documentation (Russian)](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cuser/)